# JS Strings/Numbers and Garbage Collection

Tags: javascript, string, garbage-collection

### tl;dr

Does the following line of code create an object (like a JavaScript String object or a JavaScript Number object) to combine the string primitive and the number?

```
var scouterSays = "powerlvl" + 9001;
```

### Full Question

I'm writing a game engine in JavaScript and am trying to be very careful with garbage collection. I've read through http://www.scirra.com/blog/76/how-to-write-low-garbage-real-time-javascript and http://buildnewgames.com/garbage-collector-friendly-code/ which have been very helpful. I've implemented object pooling and have avoided array manipulation in favor of linked lists whenever possible.

Now if I understand it correctly, if I call a string method on a primitive string, a string object will be created and replaces my primitive string. Examples are length, substring, indexOf, and so on. Since I use strings to identify object types with object pooling, I am concerned that I am creating garbage each time I pull an object from the pool.

In short, will the following cause an object (like a JavaScript String object or a JavaScript Number object) to be created?

```
var byteSize = 4;
var objectType = "msg" + byteSize; //does this create a JS String/Number object?
var message = gameengine.pool.acquire(objectType);
```

Also, a related question, will use of bitwise operations (like ~~() or << or >>) cause a JavaScript object to be created as well?

Comment: Why avoid arrays in favor of linked lists? The latter needs *at least* as many objects, likely more, and has less cache friendly memory layout. The cases where you really need to remove objects from the middle of the sequence are rather rare -- many games do just fine using mostly arrays. Also, have you considered typed arrays coupled with data oriented design?

Comment: I need to remove objects from a list often enough that I think linked lists are needed in many cases. Now that I think back on it though, I can use arrays instead in a few places where I won't be modifying the datastructures.

I'm unaware of typed arrays coupled with data oriented design. Could you provide a link describing it? Thanks!

Comment: As removing a reference from a container won't invalidate other references, you can easily and efficiently remove from an array too, *if* you don't need any particular order (swap the element to remove with the last element, then shrink the array by 1 which is essentially free). RE Data oriented design: http://gamesfromwithin.com/category/data-oriented-design and some of http://www.altdevblogaday.com/author/niklas-frykholm/ have taught me. I mention typed arrays because AFAIK they are more likely than regular arrays of regular numbers to actually get some of the promised performance benefits.

Comment: I've been doing a lot of reading on the subject and my conclusion so far is that I'm in over my head and shouldn't be concerned with optimizing for speed via Data Oriented Design just yet. Instead, what I did learn is that the Entity Component Model that I've built is insufficient and that I should first learn/implement an Entity System, which in turn leads to Data Oriented Design as it separates the data from the logic. Trying to wrap my head around having a Balls object with multiple arrays of data instead of a Ball object is too much for me right now. Small steps. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I'm sold on the Entity System mainly for organizational purposes rather than potential performance gains. Still, for Data Oriented Design and typed arrays, I'm now curious on what happens when I load an integer from a typed array into a variable, like var x = int32View[0], and then do math on it, like x += 5. Does it get cast to a double so I can do math on it? If so, would there be any performance benefit in using typed arrays over numbers?

Answer (score -1):

I have zero trust to JavaScript GC and this is my base reason to stay away from this language. Anyway, my attempt to reply is:

```
var x = 1;
alert(typeof x); //number

var n = new Number(1);
alert(typeof n); //object

var scouterSays = "powerlvl" + 9001;
alert(typeof scouterSays); //string

var txt = new String("string");
alert(typeof txt); //object

var test1 = new Boolean(true);
var test2 = String(test1); //convert object to string
alert(typeof test2); //string
```